# Show string in tooltip with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Here I have a name of places by google places api:

```
var ime=place.name;
```

and I call this string (object name) with tooltip into title tag:

```
content: '<div title='+ime+' class="kikonica" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"><img src='+image+'</img></div>'
```

but on hover I only see first word of title so first word of place name...

etc. if name is: `King Burger restaurant` on hover I only see `King`

Why?
How I can solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ime is a single word and you do

```
title = ' + ime + '
```

it works good and fine but when its more than a single word the space splits it up
and hence you need to concat that using a double quote as i did below

Try this

```
content: '<div title="'+ime+'" class="kikonica" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"><img src='+image+'</img></div>'
```

Comment: This works, but would you explain *why* it works as well, to better inform the OP.